# ASP.Net MVC C# Sending Notification on Session TimeOut/Browser Close

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My application needs a notification that collects all the updated records and then right after the user session/browser close it will send a summary of the Updated records on the approver thru sms. (*Our SMS is server based thats why I just need to insert the recepint message to a certain table.)

I need help on creating a concept on how will I materialize the said requirement.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API  and http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways that I can think off on how to do this:

1. As Mohayemin suggested - websockets - in ASP.NET, you could use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr). This will allow you to establish a bidirectional channel between client and server and be notified when it is closed. The problem with this technology is that if a user closes the window and opens another one just after that, you might be sending SMS because of the end of first session, but you won't be able to react to opening of the second session. Not sure if that bothers you.
2. With each request you receive from a user (and if you want an idle user with browser open on your page count as active user, you can send Ajax requests every minute or so), you updated a timestamp in the database, which will hold the value of user's last activity. Then create a background thread that works like a cron, so it is launched e.g. every 5 minutes and lists all users whose last activity is older then your limit (e.g. 15 minutes). If you find some, send SMS and mark that you processed this one (to avoid double sending). This solution solves the problem with reopening the session early after the first is closed, so it might be the one you want to use.

Comment: I like your 2nd Idea (^_^)b

Comment: Thanks, if you like it then you can upvote it. If it works for you, you can accept it is a right answer.